# save the excel file from memory stream in NPOI

Tags: c#, excel, memorystream, npoi

I'm trying to save/download the .xlsx file that derive from memory stream like this way

```
public CustomObj SaveExcelFile(string sheetName)
{
    
        var ret = new CustomObj();
   

        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        
        using (memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            IWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            ISheet sheet = workbook.CreateSheet(sheetName);
            
            ...

            workbook.Write(memStream);

            byte[] buffer = memStream.ToArray();

            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/xlsx";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=MyFile.xlsx");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
   
        }

    return ret;

}
```

once I click the save file, this is supposed to download the file, but its doesn't give any error or save file. what did I miss here ?

Comment: Try to use memStream.SaveAs(response.OutputStream);